# Where can I get a high resolution transparent version of the new .NET logo?

Tags: .net, graphical-logo

We've been using the [FCG](http://www.xheo.com/support/kb/1018/assembly+versioning.aspx) for a while to brand products and tools as .NET compatible. Microsoft has updated the look but I can't seem to find any high resolution versions of the logo.

I'd be happy with a high-res PNG, PhotoShop or Illustrator file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few different versions:

http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/images/gallery/logos/ms_net_rgb_print.tif

http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/images/gallery/logos/net_v_print.tif

More logos can be found here:
http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/gallery/ms-logos.mspx?finish=yes

Answer (score 1):

Please Check following Link to download HIGH Resolution New Microsoft Logo with Source Files

http://designerslogic.com/freebies/download-high-resolution-new-microsoft-logo-source-files-included/